# What connection does Android use when both WiFi and mobile data are simultaneously enabled?

Tags: java, android, mobile

Which connection/s does an Android use when both wifi and data connection are enabled? Does an Android use wifi or data cellular connection or both!?

Comment: Android prefers WiFi over data connection.

Comment: Actually, we all do, because it is (or should be) cheaper and faster...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

By default I believe android preferes the WiFi connection, but how is that relevant to this forum?